# Resolving git rebase deleted by Us

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a file say a.java which I have modified.

In the meantime before I push my changes to master, Another developer deleted that file (basically renamed the package).

Now when I rebase my changes, I see

```
Unmerged paths:
   deletedbyus: a.java
```

Now since I want to keep the changes,I made ..I tried git add a.java but it does not seem to work i still see

```
Unmerged path:
 deltedbyus: a.java
```

If i do git rm or rm,the file will be staged but it will show as deleted thereby removing the file alltogether.

What should be correct way to restore the file with my changes intact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are on `master` branch, and someone else pushed the the *package change* of `a.java` file to `master` and you are now doing `git rebase` on `master` branch after committing your changes, let's clarify what it exactly means:

In this situation git is resetting the `HEAD` of your `master` branch to the one of the remote `origin/master` branch. And then git is taking each of actually *your* commits and rewriting them on top of the new master's `HEAD`.

Actually they are *your* commits which are being rewritten, but from git's point of view they are the changes of *them* because they belong to the branch git is rebasing on top of your current branch (which aren't actually your changes, but it's now *our* branch, therefore *our changes*).

In this context, when git tells you `deletedbyus` it means that in the commit git is rewriting, the file exists *again*, because it has been already deleted *in our branch* (by us), but **what should I (git) do with the changes to a file that no longer exists?** Someone deleted it intentionally and I (git) cannot create the file again without confirmation (and that is correct, indeed).

So, what should you do to fix this situation? Actually you should include *your* changes (*theirs* from git's point of view during the rebase) in the location where the file now exists (on the new package, assuming you want to keep the package change). Once you have done this, you should do

```
# Manually carry the changes you made to 
# file/on/old/package/a.java 
# to file/moved/to/new/package/a.java

git add file/moved/to/new/package/a.java # To confirm your changes
git rm file/on/old/package/a.java # To confirm deletion
git rebase --continue # To continue with your rebase
```

But, which changes did you make to the file? You can see it with `git diff HEAD:file/moved/to/new/package/a.java file/on/old/package/a.java`

Comment: Thanks Manuel. Read this after a while as I had solved the problem myself but ur explanation is bang on!!